# Are LiveCards ever uploaded to google account or are they stored only on the Glass device?

Tags: android, google-glass, timeline, google-gdk

My googling has failed me on this matter. I need to present data to the user and a LiveCard seems to be the way to go in this matter. However, the data to be presented is sensitive and may on no account be uploaded to google servers. It seems to me that LiveCards aren't added to the timeline actually connected to the account but before I go any further, is this the case?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Live cards are the cards you see next to the settings card. They always reside there. They do not go on the servers. You can look at the GDK-Sample(Stopwatch, Compass) apps as reference. They insert a Live card into the timeline and they are offline.